# How to know which patches are installed on the IIS

Tags: iis

First I wanted to know which version of IIS is installed on the server. So, I got the following from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/10518/how-can-i-tell-what-version-of-iis-is-installed).

**You can look at %SYSTEMROOT%\system32\inetsrv\inetinfo.exe. Right-click and get properties, click the Version tab.**

The IIS version in my case is 6.0.3790.3959.

Now I also want to know If there are any patches installed for IIS. If yes, how to view them as a list?

Comment: Its not polite to downvote without specifying a reason for the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run a command prompt with admin rights and try this one:

> wmic qfe list full

You could pipe the results to a file and then parse by the KB number for comparisons.

Comment: Thank you. However, how one would know which patches are for IIS?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can find on Google is that there's only 1 IIS patch([Web DAV security patch](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms04-030)) (targeted directly at IIS itself) released in 2004, if you have updated using Windows Update since 2004, you should have that patch.

Most other components are usually stand alone and are either a part of .net or other CGI/FCGI/ISAPI component which are not counted directly as IIS.